# Freeeform template variables always show up

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm using variables in my notification template. This works great when a use enters a value for that field in the form. The token {name} is replaced with the value the user entered in the text input.

But when the user doesn't enter a value in the form field the token is printed in the email. {name}

I was expecting either a form value or nothing to be printed to the email notification.

Is there a way to configure this? My notifications are full of tokens that I'd like to only if print the user entered the matching field value.

patrick

Answer (score 0):

Notifications use conditionals the same way as within a template tag. to use {name} as an example, you would do the following:

```
{if name}{name}{/if}
```

This would show the value if one was entered and be disregarded if the field was left blank. However, you might want to also include a label.

```
{if name}Name: {name}{/if}
```